# How to add <= argument to query formula

Tags: api, arguments, google-sheets-api

I need some help to finish a query formula I am using to filter responses in Google Sheets.

This is what I have so far:

```
=query('Form Responses 1'!A1:Q,"Select * Where E="""&A5&""" "))
```

This works to filter my responses based on what is in A5. I need it to also not look for "COMPLETE" in the same argument, everything I have tried so far gives me an error.

Comment: have you posted the solution to your problem in the question itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the answer to the question I asked seems so simple now

SOLVED

```
=query('Form Responses 1'!A1:Q,"Select * Where Q<>'COMPLETE' and E="""&A5&""" "))
```